# Membership.CreateUser() is giving this error "Specified method is not supported"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

When I register new user using

`Membership.CreateUser(model.UserId, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus)`

I am getting the following error:

> Specified method is not supported

Please help

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserId, 
                                  model.Password, 
                                  model.Email, 
                                  null, 
                                  null, 
                                  true, 
                                  null, 
                                  out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {

                UpdateUserInfo();
                /* "False" for createPersistentCookie: */
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserId, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using SimpleMembership?  If so, then see Pinch's answer, if not please tell us what you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You must now use `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(...)`

Comment: To Clarify, if you're using SimpleMembership, you must use `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount()`.  If you're using a different membership provider you may have to use something else if CreateUser does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use ASP.NET Membership Provider for MVC4 (which is fair enough - you might have to access a legacy Membership Provider database which you don't have control over), you will need to turn SimpleMembership off (which is the default for MVC4).

Just add the following line to 'appSettings' in your Web.config:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an additional null into your method call.

The method should be as followed:

```
Membership.CreateUser(model.UserId, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, out createStatus);
```

Here's the method signature:

```
public static MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, out MembershipCreateStatus status);
```

Hopes this helps!